# Using UIProgressView as a Progress indicator for goals

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, user-interface

I've tried figuring this out on my own, and am completely clueless as to how to accomplish it. Essentially what I'm trying to do is this:
The Overall Goal: Use the `UIProgressView` as a "different type" of indicator than what it's meant for.
 Details: When a user 'completes' a 'goal' (by pressing a UIButton named "complete" in a separate `UIViewController`, let's call this one "View Controller 1") I'd like it to update a UIProgressView in a second `UIViewController` (call this one "View Controller 2"). There are several `UIProgressViews` in View Controller 2, each representing the # of goals in a category 'completed'. So I'd *like* to have a void method in `View Controller` 2 like this:

```
 (void)progressMade:(NSString *)category
{
   categoryOneProgressView.progress += 1/8 ;
   //this would be called from View Controller 1, after the "complete" button was pressed.
}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: That probably way from solving your problem but remember that 1/8 equals to 0 in c, what you need is **1.0/8**

Comment: I believe what Vladimir said is correct. Another option for accomplishing this goal is making your own progress bar with 2 UIViews overlaid - then you can fully customize it however you like. Just have a default width/height/color for the background view, then calculate the width of the overlaid bar based on progress and the default width (so defaultWidth/8 would mean you are 1/8th of the way done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is on Touching of Button in VIEW CONTROLLER 1 you store the Value of the goals completed in a particular category. Example Code for View Controller 1:

```
-(void)methodTriggeredOnCompleted:(NSString *)category
{
    //Do you calculation for progress of a category 

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setValue:saveProgressValue forKey:category];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Now in View Controller 2 what you should do is in ViewDidLoad method or in ViewWillAppear method you should get the value you stored in NSUserDefaults and update it in progress bar value

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int val = [defaults valueForKey:category];
    categoryOneProgressBar.progress = val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to rework with NSNumber's, but that was nothing...you rock!